# Improving speed for solving linear equation

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

I am working with huge data which are usually ill conditioned and runs extremely slow when I use `np.linalg.lstsq`(I'm using this function because my matrix is ill conditioned and the other functions such as `np.linalg.solve(A, B)` give wrong solution). `B` is calculated in each loop as its value changes. That is why I have placed it inside the loop although for this snipet, it is not necessary.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randn(15000, 15000)
for i in range(50000):
    B[i] = np.random.randn(15000)
    C = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B[i], rcond=None)
```

How can improve significantly the speed of such a huge matrix? Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Does `B` changes at each loop using the value of the previously calculated `C` ? If so, I'm afraid there's little we can do to avoid this slow `for` loop...

Comment: @RandomGuy, B changes at each loop and with that, calculates C. However, B does not use the value of previously calculated C

Comment: Then why do you need to calculate `B` at each loop? Can you compute it only one time, at the beginning ?

Comment: No. What I have here is just a simplistic code. With the real code, Inside the loop function, i have to perform some actions to generate the array of B and then calculate the C. It is impossible to compute B only once. I'm looping through some datapoints, and B changes with each datapoint.

Comment: `B[i] = np.random.randn(15000)` what does this mean here? B is a vector. B[i] is a number.

Comment: If A remains the same over the loop, just pre-compute SVD for A. You can use that in the LS solution. [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974193/why-does-svd-provide-the-least-squares-and-least-norm-solution-to-a-x-b)

Comment: @AxeonThra B[i] is a vector, not a number

Comment: Like @AxeonThra says, the hard part of the solution is fixed, so you can get an LU factorization of A once, and apply that to the solution of Ax=B for each B.

Comment: For a huge data like mine, the LU solution doesnt reach lstsq function in computational speed in the example in the original question.

Comment: lstsq also accepts 2d matrix for b. In this case, [If b is two-dimensional, the least-squares solution is calculated for each of the K columns of b.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).